# version number in iOS app

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

Is there any limitation regarding iOS app version number? dose Apple allows long version numbers? I know that something like 3.3.0.x.y already works in Apple store, I also saw these posts,

[iOS App Version Numbering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10526548/ios-app-version-numbering)

[iOS App - Change Version Number Scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17571138/ios-app-change-version-number-scheme)

but my question is, dose this format 3.3.0.b.x.y works on Apple store, where b is the build stamp?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are two version numbers for an app to be specified in the Info.plist

- [CFBundleVersion](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009249-102364-TPXREF106) (or Bundle Version): build version number
- [CFBundleShortVersionString](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009249-111349-TPXREF113) (Bundle Version string, short): also called marketing version, displayed to the user in the AppStore.

So you would put your build number into CFBundleVersion and use the 3.3.x scheme to display to the user.